# Django query ForeignKey object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Can somebody help me to get the ticket object at my queryset shown below?:

```
replies = sorted(
    chain(
        SupportTicketReplies.objects.filter(author=request.user, ticket=?!?!)
    ), key=attrgetter('creation_date'), reverse=True
)
```

Currently I have no idea how to filter out replies that have been attached to a ticket by a ForeignKey.

my models.py

```
class SupportTickets(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticket_id = models.IntegerField(default=ticket_id_generator, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, editable=False)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=TICKET_CATEGORY, verbose_name='Ticket Category')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    problem_description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_OF_TICKET, verbose_name='Ticket Status', default=2)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

class SupportTicketReplies(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ticket = ForeignKey(SupportTickets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Author', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content", max_length=2000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ticket` should be either an integer representing the PK of `SupportTickets` or an instance of `SupportTickets`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the `SupportTickets` by

```
ticket = SupportTickets.objects.get(ticket_id=ticket_id)
```

Then pass above ticket to

```
replies = sorted(
    chain(
        SupportTicketReplies.objects.filter(author=request.user, ticket=ticket)
    ), key=attrgetter('creation_date'), reverse=True
)
```